# How add PHPUnit autocomplete to Sublime Text 2?

Tags: phpunit, sublimetext2

I'd like to add autocomplete drop-down such as PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, PHPUnit_Framework_Assert etc. while I am typing in Sublime Text 2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called `phpunit-sublime-completions`, which can be installed to get auto completions for the phpunit asserts

[phpunit-sublime-completions](https://github.com/tkowalewski/phpunit-sublime-completions)

Comment: Doesn't quite list what he's asking in regards to the testcase classes, but it would be a very easy thing to extend, or create another based on to add the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and a couple of other ones that would.